# Sync (oswego) vs Lock (JDK5)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Just to be sure, can experts confirm that

java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock

and Doug Lea's original [Sync](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/Sync.html)

are basically the same thing but with different names.

- acquire vs lock
- release vs unlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ReentrantLock which implements Lock wraps a class called Sync. All were written by Doug Lea.  I suggest you try to use the libraries in Java.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, the source code for [java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.java.html) lists Doug Lea as its author. Same goes for many other files in that package.

```
   /*
    * This file is available under and governed by the GNU General Public
    * License version 2 only, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
    * However, the following notice accompanied the original version of this
    * file:
    *
    * Written by Doug Lea with assistance from members of JCP JSR-166
    * Expert Group and released to the public domain, as explained at
    * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain
    */
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But from a conceptual point of view, can they be regarded equivalent ?